# download a pdf file with webcrawler

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm beginning to use to the ruby programming language.  I have a ruby script to crawl pdf files on page with anemone:

```
Anemone.crawl("http://example.com") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(/\b.+.pdf/) do |page|
    puts page.url
  end
end
```

I want download page.url using gem ruby.  What gem can I use to download page.url?

Comment: Surely you can search the web for "ruby http clients" or the like?  There are many libraries that do this...

Answer (score 3):

No need for an extra gem, try this

```
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.rubyinside.com/media/",:depth_limit => 1, :obey_robots_txt => true, :skip_query_strings => true) do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(/\b.+.pdf/) do |page|
    begin
      filename = File.basename(page.url.request_uri.to_s)
      File.open(filename,"wb") {|f| f.write(page.body)}
      puts "downloaded #{page.url}"
    rescue
      puts "error while downloading #{page.url}"
    end
  end
end
```

gives

```
downloaded http://www.rubyinside.com/media/poignant-guide.pdf
```

and the pdf is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much,but I'm still having a problem.Some case,pdf files when download are interchangeable (overwritten)

Comment: which site you download from ? you can make the filename unique by adding eg a counter so that they are not overwritten and/or recreate the folderstructure from the site

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a UNIX system, maybe [`UnixUtils`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/unix_utils):

```
Anemone.crawl("http://example.com") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(/\b.+.pdf/) do |page|
    puts page.url            # => http://example.com/foo.bar
    puts UnixUtils.curl(url) # => /tmp/foo.bar.1239u98sd
  end
end
```

Comment: IMHO, `curl` is definitely an overkill here.

Comment: Requesting Curl download the file a second time, after the content is already downloaded, is a waste of bandwidth and time.